# How to show headings with no or missing TODO keyword

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file where all headings must have a TODO keyword.
I would like to search for any headings that do not have a TODO keyword.
I can do that manually of course by scrolling thru the file.
But it is a big file and that will take a long time and I may miss something.
is there a way to search for headings that do not have a TODO type associated with them?
Thanks ahead of time.......

Comment: `C-c / m TODO=""` will create a sparse tree of TODO-less items - see [Sparse Tree](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html).

Comment: Thank you NickD, once again. That works like a charm.